# Uses of for row loop in template

Tags: django

I searched in the docs but could not find tag mentioned below . I want to know where can we use it and Please provide link so i can read more about this tag.

```
{% for row in qs %} {{ row.total_income }} {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. That's just a for loop.

Comment: What docs were you looking in?

Comment: I thought that row is something else in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) might be the one you're looking for. You can use it on your templates and when you want to iterate over a list or an iterator. Follow your example:

```
{% for row in qs %}
    {{ row.total_income }}
{% endfor %}
```

- `for` `endfor` are built-in tags
- `qs` is an iterator(a list, a queryset, or whatever which allow you to iterate over in Python)
- `row` is an object in `qs` for each cycle and `row.total_income` might be a way to access to `row` keyword (row is a `dict` which has keyword `total_income`) or an attribute (row is a class object which has property `total_income`)

You can take a look at the document url above for more details

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but that `for loop` must be used inside your template.

You can find more about it here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for